Understanding Time complexity of nested sorting
I am solving this LeetCode problem 1636. Sort Array by Increasing Frequency:

Given an array of integers nums, sort the array in increasing order based on the frequency of the values. If multiple values have the same frequency, sort them in decreasing order.
Return the sorted array.

I wrote the following working code:
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        ddict = Counter(nums)
        ddict = dict(sorted(ddict.items(), key=lambda x:(x[1], x[0])))

        defDict = defaultdict(list)
        res = []
        for k, v in ddict.items():
            defDict[v].append(k)
        
        del(ddict)
        for k, v in defDict.items():
            v.sort(reverse=True)
            for val in v:
                for _ in range(k):
                    res.append(val)

        return res

I think it has a time complexity of O(n.(nlog(n)), because I am sorting each list in defaultdict for every key in the worst case.
But the time complexity analysis in LeetCode as well as AI tools like chatGPT and Perplexity AI find the time complexity to be O(nlog(n)). I am confused. Can anyone please help me understand why it's not O(n.(nlog(n))?

It is O(n.(nlog(n)). That's just not tight.

@nocomment Could you please explain further by what you mean it's not a tight bound? Probably like a an example where it can be O(n.(nlog(n)). I am confused :(

Just like for example mergesort is O(n^3). That bound isn't wrong, it's just not tight.

Are you referring to 3 way merge sort @nocomment?

No, just standard mergesort, which is also O(n log n).

Sorry :( But I don't get it, Do you have anything that I can refer to? @nocomment

You should probably refer to the definition of big-O notation. Mergesort is both O(n log n) and O(n^3). It's even O(n^1000). Just like an apple that costs less than $1 also costs less than $1000.

Sorting distinct chunks of data will still amount to O(log). For instance, let's say you have  keys in defDict, where each has a list (v) that has an average length of /, then sorting each of these v will amount to a complexity of O( (/)log(/)), which is O(log(/)), which is not worse than O(log).
Note that your v is already sorted in ascending order before the call to v.sort is made, and you could just have reversed v. As Python's native sort (timsort) deals well with such input, it will run in O() where  is the size of v, which means this part of your algorithm represents O() as time complexity, making the initial sort the determining step for what concerns the overall time complexity: O(log).

Thanks, it makes sense now.
So to summarize:
Sorting each list in defDict does not contribute significantly to the overall worst-case time complexity. Because in the worst case, each list in defDict will have a maximum size equal to the number of elements with the same frequency. This means the maximum size of any list is bounded by n (the total number of elements in nums).
Sorting a list of size m (where m <= n) in the worst case takes O(m log m) time. However, since m is always less than or equal to n, this term gets absorbed by the dominant O(n log n)

Actually their sorting of chunks only takes linear time.

@nocomment, true, as v is already sorted in ascending order before the call to sort is made. I have added a paragraph on that.

I'd use a different name for the size of v, redefining n is confusing, especially when the new definition doesn't even last until the end of the sentence, so that the same name has two different meanings within the same sentence.

good remark. Using  now.
